# call onmousedown and onclick using this inside a custom class with JS

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to make circle(army) with move when I drag it and when I click it, it should not move but do something else.

```
fucntion unit() {
    this.circle = document.createElementNS(svgNs, "circle");
    //Some attributes are added to this.circle
    document.getElementById("svg1").appendChild(this.circle);
    this.moving = false;
    this.circle.onclick = function () {
        showForm(this);
    }
    this.circle.onmousedown = function () {
        this.moving = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I know that you didn't tag jQuery in your code, but if you have looked at my other posts, I tend to go full jQuery. If you wanted to do this, do this:

let's say this applies to your circle id element:

```
$("#circle").draggable( 'enable' )
var isDragging = 0;
var isUp = 1;
$("#circle").mousedown(function() {
    isDragging = 0;
    isUp = 0;
})
$("#circle").mousemove(function() {
    isDragging = 1;
 });
$("#circle").mouseup(function() {
    isDragging = 0;
    isUp = 1;
});
$("#circle").mousedown(function() {
    if (isUp == 1) {
       //click function

    } else if (isDragging == 1) {
       //drag function
    }
});
```

This might be a little buggy, but I tried.